# Renaming collection in eXist-db in Java

Tags: java, exist-db

Hi I would like to ask if someone could tell me if it is possible to rename a collection in eXist-db in Java (without having to remove old collection and create a new one). I have already searched the API but haven't found anything except creating and removing collections. I'm using exist's XML:DB API.

Comment: Which of eXist's Java APIs are you using? XML-RPC? XML:DB? REST? XQJ? internal?

Comment: @adamretter exist's XML:DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely cast your instance of `org.xmldb.api.modules.CollectionManagementService` to `org.exist.xmldb.CollectionManagementServiceImpl`. `CollectionManagementServiceImpl` has some additional methods on it such as `move` for collections and `moveResource` for resources, among others.